# OAuth 2 implementation using YouTube API - Java

Tags: java, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was trying to implement OAuth 2 authentication in my Java code for the YouTube API, and a particular import which is present in all the samples given on the [site](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java) doesn't work:

```
import com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.Auth
```

This library does not exist in the YouTube data API v3. Is anyone aware of which external jar file has to be added to access this?

Comment: You can use API Client Library from Google  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

Comment: @Verma - I'm not sure if I understood correctly. I checked the link given, but I don't find any mention of the Auth library there.

Comment: That's not in the API, it's just some sample code on the Youtube Github. You can either copypasta that or make your own class.